# NSMutableDictionary containing NSMutableArray returns a string

Tags: iphone, cocoa, nsmutablearray, nsmutabledictionary

I am trying to store a variety of strings and a NSMutableArray in a NSMutableDictionary. Basically an XML element with various key/values and one subelement with a list.

```
        NSMutableArray *subItem = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease];
        for (GDataXMLElement *subElement in [key children]){
            [subItem addObject:[[[self runThroughElement:subElement] copy] autorelease]];
        }
        [item setObject:[[subItem copy] autorelease] forKey:[key name]];
```

When I check the type:

```
NSLog(@"Categories type: %@", [[item objectForKey: @"categories"] classForCoder]);
```

I get:

> Categories type: NSArray

But then in the function which deals with the data and stores it in an object it suddenly appears to be a string:

```
    NSLog(@"Categories type: %@", [[obj objectForKey: @"categories"] classForCoder]);
```

Which results in:

> Categories type: NSString

I am at a loss what is going wrong, why do I get a string out of the dictionary and not the array I put into it? Any help would be really appreciated!
(probably need more info, so please let me know what is relevant)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't really be using classForCoder. Instead just log **[[obj objectForKey:@"categories"] class]**. I'd also try logging the straight **[obj objectForKey:@"categories"]** to see if it does output a string or an array. If it outputs a string then either obj is not item or your dictionary is being modified at some point.

One bit of advice, there isn't any reason to do [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease]. Just call [NSMutableArray array]. Does the same thing but  with less code. Same goes for many classes, look for convenience class methods to save you having to do alloc/init/autorelease.

Comment: When logging it straight it does give the right value in the first instance:Categories type: (
        {
        text = 1;
    }
But when calling it back it returns nothing. It must be something stupid, but I don't know where...

Comment: When you set item to the obj variable, how do you do it? It should probably be "obj = [item copy]"

Comment: Yes, I use: [item setObject:[[subItem copy] autorelease] forKey:[key name]]; Item is the MutableDictionary, and subItem is the Array.

I don't know if it makes a difference, but these are subsequent added to another Array, but I always use the copy - autorelease combination as shown above.

Comment: I solved it, there was a data problem in the XML feed. Sorry for wasting your time!